# Issue with asynchronously removing displayed data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, async-await

I am testing with the following code to display data and then remove it after a certain time, using async.

The problem I am having is that I want to display the label and text, then do the async however the async is running before the first part of my code.

Is there a way that I am able to run the code first and then do the async await?

```html
<form id="form1" ondatabound="Page_Load()" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="false"></asp:Label><br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="btn btn-error" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" /><br /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ReadOnly="false" Text="" Visible="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" ReadOnly="false" Text="" Visible="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    </div>
</form>
```

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TextBox1.Text = "TestEmail";
        //TextBox2.Text = "TestPassword";
    }

    //When Button1 is clicked then show/hide the title label
    protected void Button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Label1.Visible == false)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "Please use this link to login: www.test.com";
            TextBox1.Text = "TestingData";
        }
        else
            Label1.Visible = false;
        ClearMessages();
    }

    public async Task SyncTest()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000); // 5 second delay
        this.ClearMessages();
    }

    protected void ClearMessages()
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "";
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        Label1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use await the thread will wait for the method to be executed and then continue. However, I'm not sure if you can still pass information if the page has been rendered and passed to the client. You can solve this clientside by calling a script to clean after 5 seconds.

Comment: I think you should look into client side code (JavaScript) to display/hide text. Your asp.net code runs on the server!

Comment: You seem to be thinking that async/await will enable you to change already rendered page in the browser. It won't, there is javascript for that.

Comment: you can do this with ViewState and StateManager (ajax), but I'm not sure if such a consideration really has anything to do with tasks and async.. since the XHR call and mechanics would essentially be the asynchronous aspect.

Comment: don't accept the first answer provided ae07etw.  there are several framework supported manners to do this, and the community will upvote the best one.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, this has bettered my understanding immensely.

Comment: opps.. I meant to say ViewState and ScriptManager (ASP.NET Ajax - Partial Page Updates) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in the comment. As soon as the page is rendered the backend has no connection to the page anymore thus it cannot empty the text. The better way to solve this would be to clean it on clientside by calling the script on clientside with

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "cleanText", "cleanText());", true);
```

this will call the method below which will empty textbox1 after 5 seconds.

```
function cleanText(){
   setTimeout(function() { 
   var txt1 = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
   txt1.value = "";}, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and feedback, it is much appreciated. I have learned a lot from this and will look into researching and implementing the above code.

Comment: this answer is informative and relates to the desired result of the OP as well as an aspect of the issue, but doesn't actually answer the question or the reflect the desired implementation of the OP: which is to have an asynchronous (callback) that can handle control viewstates.  You can use register scripts in the ScriptManager for partial page updates as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.7.2 which does support these considerations.

Comment: of course, adding xhr callbacks and partial page updates is less accurate in timing - that is certainly a consideration; this answer's implementation  is more reliable in the sense of timing.

Comment: @BrettCaswell I'm a little confused by your comment since you link to the same solution i provided but still say its not the way to go. Can you provide a better answer, thx

Comment: I see where it is confusing, I'm not linking you to the same solution. The method I linked to is a method off of `ScriptManager`, the one you're referencing above is a method off of `ClientScriptManager`, and you can see in the remarks section on the link I provided that they different, and serve different purposes. "If you want to register a startup script that does not pertain to partial-page updates, and if you want to register the script only one time during initial page rendering, use the RegisterStartupScript method of the ClientScriptManager class"

Comment: @BrettCaswell gotcha thanx for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

regarding your concept and question:

> ...remove [data] after a certain time, using `async` [, or awaitable `Task`].
>
> Is there a way that I am able to [render the page] and then do the `async` `await`?

to my knowledge, there is no framework support for `async` `await` and `Task` to cross [Page Lifecycles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), let alone compose mechanisms on a post rendered/unloaded page, so the answer is likely, **no**.

---

There is, however, asynchronous support for WebForm Applications with [ASP.NET AJAX Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/). You can achieve your desired behavior (code behind handling of control property changes in an asynchronous manner) with [Partial Page Updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-partial-page-updates-with-asp-net-ajax#partial-page-updates).